# Normal modes of a drum and Kac's question: Can one hear the shape of a drum?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, music-theory

I consider a vibrating membrane $D\subset {\mathbb{R}}^2 $, fixed on $\partial D$. The vertical displacement $f=f(x,y,t)$ of the membrane satisfies the wave equation. I search solutions of the form $f(x,y,t)=g(x,y)h(t)$ and I obtain:
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{cases} \Delta\:g+ \lambda \:g=0\quad {\rm in}\;D  \\ g=0\quad {\rm on} \; \partial D.\end{cases}
 \end{equation*}
, with $\lambda>0$.

I know that I can obtain a general oscillation of the membrane as superposition of normal modes, which are determined by the eigenvalues of the Laplacian. So I have that the sound that can emit my drum can be deduced univocally from the spectrum of the Laplacian (which depends on the the domain $D$).

I would like to know if this assertion is true and e if it is expressed correctly:

a person with a perfect ear, capable of identifying all the frequencies of the modes of vibration, can identify the shape of the drum just from hearing these frequencies $iff$ the domain $D$ is uniquely determined by the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.

This is Kac's question: `Can one hear the shape of a drum?'. Is this a correct formulation of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a correct formulation, but the answer is no: there are domains of different shapes whose Laplacians have the same spectrum.  See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum)